# Is there any possibility to save kable table in .tex or .markdown?

Tags: r, dataframe, knitr, kable

Let's consider very simple kable table for reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame("X_1" = c(1, 2), "X_2" =c(3,4))
df <- kable(df, format = 'latex')
df

\begin{tabular}{r|r}
\hline
X\_1 & X\_2\\
\hline
1 & 3\\
\hline
2 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Is there any possibility to have this file saved as .tex or .markdown ? I looked for function `save_kable` but it seems that it only supports `.png`, `.pdf` or `.jpeg` formats.

Comment: save_kable(df,'df.tex') does the trick for me, although there is an empty line in the beginning and end of the file. Usually if .txt is supported, so is .tex. This might not always be mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`knitr::kable()` returns a character vector, which you can definitely write to a file, e.g.,

```r
df <- data.frame("X_1" = c(1, 2), "X_2" =c(3,4))
df <- knitr::kable(df, format = 'latex')
writeLines(df, 'df.tex')
```

Answer (score 5):

i am using `save_kable` and specifying tex with no problems e.g. `%>% save_kable(paste(resultspath,"DescTableStroops.tex"),float = FALSE)`

Comment: `save_kable()` is a function from the {kableExtra} package, if anyone is wondering. Make sure to set `format = "latex"` in your kable for this to work.

Comment: What does the `float = FALSE` option do?

Comment: By the way, this should be the accepted answer, in my opinion, since the question asked about `save_kable` explicitly.